# Saving variables with localStorage does not work correctly

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I'm writing a function that saves me some time-persistent variables (I don't have a backend and I don't need it for this exercise), but I notice that the first variable "easy30" saves it in the html and every time I reload the page remains visible, while the second variable "easy60" does not remain. It only saves it the first time and if I reload the page it disappears... why? I basically do the exact same thing for both variables!

```
 const easy30 = document.getElementById('easy-30');
 const easy60 = document.getElementById('easy-60');

 function saveScoreAndTime(score, time, difficulty) {
   //EASY 30 SECONDS
   var totalScore30 = localStorage.getItem('score30');

   if (
     totalScore30 === null ||
     (+score > +totalScore30 && +time === 30 && difficulty === 'easy')
   ) {
     localStorage.setItem('score30', score);
     let newEasy30Score = localStorage.getItem('score30');
     easy30.textContent = newEasy30Score;
   }

   //EASY 60 SECONDS
   var totalScore60 = localStorage.getItem('score60');

   if (
     totalScore60 === null ||
     (+score > +totalScore60 && +time === 60 && difficulty === 'easy')
   ) {
     localStorage.setItem('score60', score);
     let newEasy60Score = localStorage.getItem('score60');
     easy60.textContent = newEasy60Score;
   }

 }
```

Comment: How do you call this function? I mean, what parameters do you pass?

Comment: some strings but inside there are always numbers, so for safety I transform them into numbers with the +

Comment: let me create a snippet for you. The thing is that you are targeting the HTML node `document.getElementById('easy-30')` and that will give you the HTML node, you need to get the inner text of the node to get the value

Comment: @Luke_C What means the plus  `(+score > +` infront of score?

Comment: Maik the plus turns the element into a string, it's like doing a parseInt()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So there is a problem with your code.

Why you are getting the HTML node instead of the value is because you are targeting the HTML node and forgot to add the `innerHTML`

so in your case you should do
`const easy30 = document.getElementById("easy-30").innerHTML;`
to get the value of that HTML node

also here is an example to get and set the localstorage

```
const easy30 = document.getElementById("easy-30");
const easy60 = document.getElementById("easy-60");
console.log("easy30", easy30.innerHTML);
console.log("easy60", easy60.innerHTML);

const init = async () => {
  const score30 = await localStorage.getItem("easy30");
  console.log("score30", score30);
  const score60 = await localStorage.getItem("easy60");
  console.log("score30", score60);
};

init();

const setLocalStorage = async (key) => {
  localStorage.setItem(key, 30);
};
setLocalStorage("score30");
setLocalStorage("score60");
```

and here is a codesandbox snippet

Comment: if you still having a problem, just write and I will explain it